# Node Package for permanently recording info?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

So, when I run my code. I want to have a variable be recorded permanently to something. I was wondering if there was a node package for this or another option for doing this.

I want to be able to access it when I restart my server. I dont want to lose the data.

Example (Let's call this "runMe.js")

```
var exampleTest = "Hello World";
```

When I run the file, I want to record this info permanently somewhere.

I will be storing simple string. Like the example above.

Comment: "permanent" varies in definition. but you could try localstorage of the browser

Comment: You have a lot of options like plain files, json files, databases, etc. What kind of data you need to store? How data will be accessed (multiple concurrent readers/writers etc.)?

Comment: Scrooj, by permanent I mean able to view it after restarting the server. Ivan, I am just trying to store simple strings. I am hoping to access the data from my browser.

Comment: @Samuel You mean, like a database?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 To sum it up, my goal is to store strings somewhere that I can view while the server is on or off. Also, I want that data to be available after I restart the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were this on the browser, using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) would be a no-brainer.  However, this is Node.JS, so you can use [node-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-localstorage) for now.

However, you may want to look into more advanced solutions like a database.  [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) allows one to store data in JSON, so it should be familiar to any JS developer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I decided to use node-localstorage and things are working out nicely.